# Unable to connect OPENVPN vpn on WIFI on UBUNTU 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn, openvpn

New user! Just installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Installed Openvpn, configured the client and used the following commands to install network manager "nmcli" and tried to connect client.

Getting time out.

$ sudo apt-get install network-manager network-manager-openvpn

$ cd ~/

$ sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file client.ovpn

$ nmcli connection up client

getting timeout error.... Why?

---

**using dpkg -l I've got the following details:**

```
ii  openvpn                                    2.4.4-2ubuntu1.3                             amd64        virtual private network daemon

ii  wpasupplicant                              2:2.6-15ubuntu2.3                            amd64        client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)
```

---

**Using grep -i vpn /var/log/syslog* got the following details of openvpn log:**

```
/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 07:40:35 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1702]: Initialization Sequence Completed

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 08:41:26 syed007-K53SD gsd-housekeepin[3000]: Failed to enumerate children of >/var/tmp/systemd-private-4a81781c01ad49b6b3c36f8bbad324b7-openvpn-server@server.service-ScMdFg: Error opening directory '>/var/tmp/systemd-private-4a81781c01ad49b6b3c36f8bbad324b7-openvpn-server@server.service-ScMdFg': Permission denied

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 08:41:26 syed007-K53SD gsd-housekeepin[3000]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-4a81781c01ad49b6b3c36f8bbad324b7-openvpn-server@server.service-jvwner: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-4a81781c01ad49b6b3c36f8bbad324b7-openvpn-server@server.service-jvwner': Permission denied

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:25 syed007-K53SD systemd[1]: Starting openvpn-iptables.service...

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:25 syed007-K53SD systemd[1]: Started openvpn-iptables.service.

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:25 syed007-K53SD kernel: [    8.245210] systemd[1]: Created slice system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice.

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:30 syed007-K53SD systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service...

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:30 syed007-K53SD systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service.

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:40 syed007-K53SD systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service for server...

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:41 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:41 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:41 syed007-K53SD systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service for server.

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.1/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: GID set to nogroup

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: UID set to nobody

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.2 size=252, ipv6=0

/var/log/syslog:Aug 12 15:45:42 syed007-K53SD openvpn[1611]: IFCONFIG POOL LIST
```

---

The result of command $ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf is as below:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug  2 18:12 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

---

The command $ cat /etc/resolv.conf gives following output:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

---

The result of command $ sudo openvpn client.ovpn is as below:

```
Tue Aug 13 06:14:04 2019 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in client.ovpn:14: block-outside-dns (2.4.4)

Tue Aug 13 06:14:04 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019

Tue Aug 13 06:14:04 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08

Tue Aug 13 06:14:04 2019 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication

Tue Aug 13 06:14:04 2019 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication

Tue Aug 13 06:14:04 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]201.0.111.11:1194

Tue Aug 13 06:14:04 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]

Tue Aug 13 06:14:04 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)

Tue Aug 13 06:14:04 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]201.0.111.11:1194

Tue Aug 13 06:15:04 2019 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)

Tue Aug 13 06:15:04 2019 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed

Tue Aug 13 06:15:04 2019 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting

Tue Aug 13 06:15:04 2019 Restart pause, 5 second(s)

Tue Aug 13 06:15:09 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]201.0.111.11:1194

Tue Aug 13 06:15:09 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]

Tue Aug 13 06:15:09 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)

Tue Aug 13 06:15:09 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]201.0.111.11:1194
```

Comment: Without seeing any log files, I'll take a wild guess... is `wpasupplicant` installed?

Comment: how can I view the log file please?

Comment: `dpkg -l wpasupplicant` to see if wpasupplicant is installed. `grep -i vpn /var/log/syslog*` to view logs. `sudo openvpn client.ovpn` to connect and obtain some log info.

Comment: status please...

Comment: cannot add here its a big file of 234 lines.

Comment: use paste.ubuntu.com. Also tell me about the `dpkg` and `openvpn` commands that I gave you. The openvpn command should give a shorter, but possibly more useful log.

Comment: Thanks Thomas ward for editing and adding log file contents and deleting the answer,

Comment: Thanks heynnema for giving me dpkg and openvpn commands. dpkg -l gave output of all the packages installed. Found Openvpn too. grep - vpn /var/log/syslog* gave complete log of openvpn. Got the log and pasted above in the question itself by Mr. Thomas.

Comment: Show me the **exact** output of `dpkg -l wpasupplicant` and `dpkg -l *openvpn*` and `sudo openvpn client.ovpn`. Your wireless connection works fine without VPN, correct? Do `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome` to install additional software.

Comment: pasted the exact output of dpkg -l wpa supplicant and dpkg - l openvpn and sudo openvpn client.ovpn.  Yes my wireless connection works fine without openvpn.  Yes network manager installed to run commands  sudo -i and  nmcli connection up client so as to connect openvpn using nmcli from root login.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. However, I don't see the output of `sudo openvpn client.ovpn`. When adding output to your question, paste the text, select the text, and then hit the {} icon to format the text.

Comment: Also show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me heynnema, added the results to the above. I've one doubt that when I was installing OpenVPN it asked for a public address which I gave some address. But I don't have any such public IP, Is it not connecting because of that public address?

Comment: I'm still am waiting to see the output of `sudo openvpn client.ovpn`.

Comment: Dont know how I missed that. Thanks for your patience Mr. Heynnema. Added the result of sudo openvpn client.ovpn

Comment: After all of your hard work, I'm sorry, but I don't have an answer for you. Maybe somebody else can chime in.